# Athena Query result location through terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-athena

I have created athena work group through terraform and athena query result location is not updating in query editor. In athena workgroup i can see my s3 bucket name in query result location but i don't see it in query editor. Is my code need any correction ?

```
resource "aws_athena_workgroup" "this" {
  name       = var.name
  depends_on = [module.s3]
  configuration {
    bytes_scanned_cutoff_per_query     = var.bytes_scanned_cutoff_per_query
    enforce_workgroup_configuration    = true
    publish_cloudwatch_metrics_enabled = true
    result_configuration {
      output_location = "s3://athena-stage-workgroup/"
      encryption_configuration {
        encryption_option = "SSE-KMS"
        kms_key_arn       = var.kms_key_arn
      }
    }
  }
  force_destroy = true
}
```

athena query:

```
resource "aws_athena_named_query" "this" {
  name        = "athena-query"
  workgroup   = aws_athena_workgroup.this.id
  database    = aws_athena_database.default.name
  query       = "SELECT * FROM red-table limit 10;"
  description = "testing"
```

after i run terraform apply, i can see the s3 location only in:
[image]

and i don't see the Query result location in query editor:

[image]

do i need to update anything in code ?

Comment: Is the query created with terraform as well? Have you chosen the right workgroup before running the query on the top right?

Comment: @MarkoE I have updated the question with athena named query resource block which i used.

Comment: Have you checked inside of the bucket are there any query results or this code does not work?

Comment: i checked in the bucket i don't see any objects and code is working fine but s3 bucket results location is not updating in query editor.

Comment: we can mark this question as done. I forgot to change the athena workgroup in query editor that's cause an error.